# sorting a multi-dimensional array at 2nd level by value php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

> I have an multi-dimensional array and i want to sort values at 2nd level alphabetically

```
$shop = array(
"director" => Array
    (
        "0" => 'Sushil Majumdar',
        "1" => 'Jyotirmoy Ray',
        "3" => 'Phani Gangopadhyay',
        "5" => 'Chitta Bose',
        "6" => 'Satyajit Ray',
        "7" => 'Ajoy Kar'
    ),

    "producer" => Array
    (
        "0" => 'Bharat Lokchitram Ltd.',
        "1" => 'Lokbani Chitrapratisthan',
        "2" => 'Rama Chhayachitra',
        "3" => 'Poddar Pictures',
        "4" => 'Rama Chhayachitra Ltd.',
        "5" => 'Chhayachitra Parishad',
        "6" => 'Government of West Bengal',
        "7" => 'Bikash Ray Productions',
        "8" => 'Epic Films'
    )
);
$keys = array('director'=>1);

foreach ($shop as $k => $v){
    if(array_key_exists($k, $keys)){
       foreach ($v as $ke => $ve){
            sort($shop[$k]);

       }
    }
}
```

> Though it can sort but somehow its not affected in my result
>   so how can i sort my array values alphabetically in ascending order

Comment: working https://3v4l.org/bstfu

Comment: is there any other way out

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet is working. But the for each loop you used to iterate over $v does not playing any role in the sorting. So you can remove that one. 
Keep like;

```
foreach ($shop as $k => $v){
    if(array_key_exists($k, $keys)){
        sort($shop[$k]);
    }
}
print_r($shop);  //alphabetically sorted values under "director" key
```

If you print the $shop array, you will find the values under  "director" key sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to sort your array at 2nd level:

```
function sortOnKeys($array, array $keys) {
    foreach ($array as $k => $v){
        if(array_key_exists($k, $keys)){
            sort($array[$k]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}



 /* set your keys */
$keys = array('director' => 1, 'producer' => 2);


/* invoke the sorting function */
$sorted = sortOnKeys($shop, $keys);


echo '<pre>';
var_dump($sorted);
echo '</pre>';
```